# Load text from php and alert--nothing shows up in alert box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to show some text that has been loaded from a php file and alert it. The issue is that nothing shows up in the alert box.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".col-md-8").load('test.php');
    var pgmonth = $('.col-md-8').text();
    alert (pgmonth);
});
```

PHP (test.php):

```
<?php
    echo "Test";
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cause ajax(load function) is not completed.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".col-md-8").load('test.php',function(){
             var pgmonth = $('.col-md-8').text();
             alert (pgmonth);
        });        
});
```